# UnicodeDecodeError when I set recursive=True in FilePathField in django

Tags: python, django

The error happened when I add record in admin. My model is like

> ```
> class THMusic(models.Model):
>      originmusic = models.ForeignKey(Originalmusic)
>      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>      audiofile = models.FilePathField(path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/resource', recursive=True)
>      team = models.CharField(max_length=50)
>      album = models.CharField(max_length=50)
> class THMusicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>      list_display = ('name', 'originmusic', )
> ```

But I get UnicodeDecodeError:

> UnicodeDecodeError at /admin/thmusic/thmusic/add/

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8006/admin/thmusic/thmusic/add/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:    

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py in __init__, line 1057
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/hyzhappy/djangoprojects/myblog',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson-3.6.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg',
 '/home/hyzhappy/djangoprojects/myblog',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

If I delete "recursice=True" in FilePathField, it will go well. But it's not my expectation
More detail

> Unicode error hint
>       The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: urce/������
>       UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', '/home/hyzhappy/djangoprojects/myblog/thmusic/resource/\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x83\xa4\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x82\xba\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x82\xb3\xe3\x82\xa2.mp3', 54, 55, 'ordinal not in range(128)')

Comment: Please include full tracebacks of errors.

Comment: According to Django's documentation, the `recursive` parameter "includes" sub-directories in the path you provided. The default is False. Might it be that one of the sub-directories has a character that is not ascii in it?

Comment: Why do you have `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/resource'`? The `dirname` of `x + "/y"` is going to be `x`.

Comment: I have no sub-directory. And os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/resource' does work.

Comment: Well, of course it works, but it does the same as just `os.path.abspath(___file___)`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the right answer, but you can check this as a possible cause.

Sometimes in Django (I had the same case with tastypie), the UnicodeDecodeError occurs because of an initial unrelated error which tries to display but can not because of weird character.

In my case, it was because I put French accents in my code comments (not ascii). This usually does not create errors, but when there is actually an error somewhere and Django tries to display this error in the debug mode, it can not because of the non ascii chars and raises a UnicodeDecodeError instead of raising the initial error.

Just try to remove any suspicious character in your code (if there is any), and check again to see if the error is still the same.

Comment: No weird character in my code or comment. Weird characters are in my database. As you see, I have a FilePathField, which contains lots of file names. And these file names may have weird characters.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, `FilePathField` uses `os.walk`/`os.listdir` to find the files. These functions have two "modes" of operation in python: byte string and unicode. The mode is selected by the type of path given, i.e. if you feed it an `unicode` string, the resulting file list will be `unicode`, otherwise it will be a byte string.

So, to fix this problem, just feed a unicode path to the `FilePathField`, like this (note the `u` at the beginning of `u'/resource'`):

```
audiofile = models.FilePathField(path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+u'/resource', recursive=True)
```